# How to install R kernel for IPython on OSX?

Tags: r, homebrew, libcurl, jupyter-notebook, rcurl

As described in [this](http://www.michaelpacer.com/maths/r-kernel-for-ipython-notebook) tutorial, I try to install `RCurl` doing

```
>install.packages('RCurl')
```

After selecting a mirror, I get:

> ```
> --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
> Warning message:
> package ‘RCurl’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
> ```

I've also updated `RCurl` with `homebrew` as:

```
$brew install --with-libressl curl
```

I already have a `RCurl` version installed

```
library('RCurl')
Loading required package: bitops
```

But I still can't see R as a kernel on IPython notebook

[image: Kernels]

Comment: have you checked the README? https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel

Comment: Thanks, silly from me to rely more on a blog than the proper README